# How can I add a span element to an img, then wrap everything with a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML source, I only have:

```
<img src="..."/>
```

Now I want to add a span with jQuery in order to get `<img src="..."/><span>My span</span>`, and after this use `.wrap()` to wrap it all around a link, to get something like this in the end:

```
<a href="#"><img src="..."/><span>My span</span></a>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
$('img').wrap('<a href="#">').after('<span>My span</span>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ykdgd/